# Clover: no test results could be found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, clover

We are just starting using Clover in our project and after 16h of work I still cannot get it to cooperate with me.

We have multimodule project built with maven3 and tycho. Tests are separated from code and placed in subdirectory tests. To build the project we use mvn clean install in main directory and then mvn clean install in tests directory to run tests. Pom in tests directory is child of main pom.

I've already tried to:

1. use `mvn clean clover2:setup install` in main directory and then `mvn clean clover2:setup install clover2:aggregate clover2:clover`
2. use `singleCloverDatabase` set to true
3. use `cloverDatabase` to point out to db location
4. use `clover2:instrument` instead of `clover2:setup`

clover.db is generated.

In maven logs for main part I have messages like

`[INFO] Clover all over. Instrumented 3 files (3 packages).`,

In maven logs for tests I have messages like:

```
[INFO] Clover all over. Instrumented 76 files (16 packages).

[INFO] 447 test methods detected.
```

Maven reports no errors.

But when I open generated html all I see is
["No test results"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCzUU.png) message.
What can possibly be wrong with our configuration? Where to look for the source of the problem?

I've asked the same question in Atlassian Answers but I've received no answer so far (https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/32014462/clover-no-test-results-could-be-found.)

Comment: Do you have the plugin configured in both the `build` and `reporting` sections of the POM?  Build plugin generates the database, report plugin generates the HTML/XML/whatever reports using the info in the clover.db.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with Maven-Tycho Plugin-Clover integration, have you tried [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+Clover+with+Maven+Tycho+Plugin) tutorial?

Comment: I found it yesterday, I have no idea how I managed to overlook it previously.
Anyway - I have coverage data collected, so it is a huge progress. Problem is - when I build my tests that were instrumented - ones that use `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` are failing with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/runner/TestRunListener`. As for now - I have no idea why.